# Periodic geodesics in special unitary groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Looking at the solution of the equation of motion for the action using a bi-invariant metric on a Lie group. If I take the lie group as $SU(2)$ the geodesics are always periodic because $SU(2)$ is the three-sphere, how can I prove this more formally?

Besides, I don't see clear how can I say something about periodic solutions in $SU(3)$ or in general in $SU(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126006/is-it-true-that-the-geodesics-on-son-and-sun-are-closed and the comments below it completely answer your question.

Edit: you seem to be under the impression that geodesics in a compact group are the same as one parameter subgroups.  Unfortunately this is usually not the case.  See here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81590/one-parameter-subgroup-and-geodesics-on-lie-group

Comment: Well my doubt is in the sense of how to show that exp(tX) for any X in the lie algebra is a closed curve in SU(2) and in what cases exp(tX) is closed in SU(3)

Comment: @Jesus see my edit.